# how to convert String date in to 29-nov-2011 format in android

Tags: android, simpledateformat

Hello every one I have one question regarding date format. I am making an android app which takes date from the database and display on the screen but I want when user view that date it should be in 29-nov-2011 format. I tried many codes but failed.. Please help me.

My stored date format is dd/mm/yyyy.

Here is my code.
**dt** means date come from the database and I passed it into function to change my date format.

```
public void change_Date(String dt) {
    try{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In change()", 
                                                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
        Date d = sdf.parse(dt);
        String str = sdf.format(d);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Date="+str, 
                                                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: While formatting it, format it with this DateFormat `dd-MMM-yyyy` and check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void change_Date(String dt)
    {
        try
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In change()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
            Date d = sdf.parse(dt);

            SimpleDateFormat sdfddMMMyyyy = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
            String str = sdfddMMMyyyy.format(d);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Date="+str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

[SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
String date = format.format(Date.parse("Your date string"));
```

Comment: "mistakenly posted" ? what do you mean ?

Comment: @ Nirav Ranpara- i have post after your answer..but didn't know u have already given right answer..anyways have a good day..!

Comment: @Riddhi Shah- i am glad to know..!

Answer (score 0):

Use `SimpleDateFormat` java class to format your date:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

In your case the format would be "dd-MMM-yyyy"

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
String date = format.format(Date.parse("Your date string"));
```

and you must import `java.util.Date`